# Fsharp: Passing N Parameters for a function

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a variable amount of parameters but I can't seem to find any viable solution for F#.

```
let expression = (fun a b -> a || b)
let expressionTriple = (fun a b c -> (a || b) && c)

// This doesn't work because expression can either be a function that takes fixed arguments
let truthTable numPredicates expression =
    if numPredicates = 2 then
        expression true true
    else
        expression true true false


truthTable 2 expression
truthTable 3 expressionTriple
```

How can I pass in a variable amount of arguments into the expression function?

Comment: What do you want `truthTable 3 expression` to do?

Comment: truthTable 3 indicates the number of predicates I'm passing in

Comment: Yes, but `expression` only takes 2 arguments so `expression true true false` would normally be a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In F#, functions with different signatures (including a different number of parameters) are considered distinct types. And any time you want to have a function take a parameter that could be two distinct types (or even a dozen distinct types), you need to use [discriminated unions](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/). Here's how you could write your code in a way that will compile and do what you're trying to do:

```
type Expression<'a> =
    | Double of ('a -> 'a -> 'a)
    | Triple of ('a -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a)

let expression = fun a b -> a || b
let expressionTriple = fun a b c -> (a || b) && c

// This works because expression is a discriminated union
let truthTable expression =
    match expression with
    | Double f -> f true true
    | Triple f -> f true true false

truthTable (Double expression)
truthTable (Triple expressionTriple)
```

If you wanted to add a four-parameter version, just add a `Quad of ('a -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a)` case to that discriminated union, and so on.

If you have any questions about this, like why I wrote this with generic type `'a` instead of `bool`, please feel free to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: The other option is overloading, but I wouldn't use overloading to model an arbitrary truth table. It simply doesn't feel right.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to arbitrary N parameters? My current workaround is to use ParamArray https://github.com/rudresh4/discite/blob/52c95bf507b2b706ffeb24277c384ec57477667e/fsharp/99-problems/48-logical-expression/LogicalExpressionTest.fs#L28

Comment: I see from your Github repo that you're working through the 99 Problems set, and this is problem 48. The only solution I've seen to that problem so far involved making your `expression` a function that takes a list. E.g., the problem statement at http://www.fssnip.net/ar/title/NinetyNine-F-Problems-Problems-46-50-Logic-and-Codes wants you to define a function `tablen` that could be called like `tablen 3 (fun [a;b;c] -> a && (b || c) = a && b || a && c)`. Your `ParamArray` solution isn't too far off from that.

Comment: But in general, no, you can't have a function signature with N arbitrary parameters in F#. As you've already found, you can use an array or a list, which is passed as a single parameter. The reason for this restriction is because it would cause problems with [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/) and [partial function application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/): if your function allowed for multiple parameters, how would the compiler know when you wanted it to be partially applied? So to allow currying, multiple parameters are forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

```
let expression = (fun [a; b] -> a || b)
let expressionTriple = (fun [a; b; c] -> (a || b) && c)

let truthTable numPredicates expression =
   if numPredicates = 2 then
      expression [true; true]
   else
      expression [true; true; false]


truthTable 2 expression 
truthTable 3 expressionTriple
```